# Does Passover sacrifice make atonement?

Tags: passover, kaparah-atonement, korban-pesach

Is Passover lamb (paschal or pesach feast) said to be atonement and not just commemorative of the original Passover sacrifice in Egypt?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20791&st=&pgnum=139&hilite= http://www.etzion.org.il/he/04-%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%9F-%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97-%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D#_ftnref24 http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/839759/rabbi-dr-j-david-bleich/%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%9F-%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97-%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%A4%D7%A8/

Comment: Why do you think it might be?

Comment: if this section of talmud refers only to passover then it is full of "atonement" references; may be you can give an overview after reading whole http://juchre.org/talmud/pesachim/pesachim4.htm#89a @MonicaCellio

Comment: The word kipper here is not linked to atonement of sin  @Michael16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched in Rambam [hilchot Korban Pessach](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/9100.htm) and if I don't miss something, no Kappara (atonement) is mentioned.

*Thanks to the answer of mevaqesh*  we can see [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40744&st=&pgnum=392&hilite=) the  Tif'eret Israel who is astonished by the Tosfot Yom Tov comparison between Pessach and taanit about  Kappara. The astonishing of Tif'eret Israel is perhaps also due to the lack of sources.

But after an accurate lecture of **Tosfot Yom Tov,  he also not said that the Pessach is Kappara** . He said  a comparison between the sets: the  set of  korbanot and the set of  taaniot (not a comparison between the two items Pessach and taanit).  The major feature of the set of  korbanot is Kappara and  the set of taaniot also.  So Pessach as an item of the set of korbanot which is mainly characterized by  capara.  So the name capara is linked to pessach by his specie.

But the [Levush Hachur OC 468, 1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9223&st=&pgnum=144&hilite=)  **also  found by  @mevaqesh**  doesn't support this  teruts.  Anyway here It is probably right  to answer that to make himself exempt from caret because bitul mitsvat asse of Korban Pessach is the called  Kappara but  **not at the sense of taanit.**

So as suggested by the lecture of Rambam (and Gemara and Tora ) Pessach is not a Korban  Kappara and **even the authors cited as thinking that it's Kappara don't really said that.**

Comment: @kouty My issue wasn't that you would borrow sources from my answer; you did reference me, and that was enough. My issue was, that I felt that the core of your answer was an argument form ignorance, and a poor one at that. So this would be the equivalent of copying an entire answer, properly attributing it, then degrading it with a poor argument. However, its you business, and your answer. Its not such a big deal, after all.

Comment: I love my teruts for  Tosfot Yom  Tov.  If you think that Tif'eret Israel has  different sources  it may be interesting.  I searched in Gemara and is I don't  miss somewhat the is no evidence of Kappara.

Comment: @kouty tanit means fasting? we should assume all animal sacrifices are meant for atonement for Lev 17:11 rashi and Hertz rightly admits atonement is on basis of blood. So kapara shouldnt be limited to regular sacrifices and yom kippur but pesach is same as yom kippur.

Comment: @Michael16 taanit is fasting right.  The principle of blood for Kappara is known.  But here the question is about a concrete issue

Answer (score 3):

R. Menashe Klein authored an entire resopnsum on this topic (Mishneh Halakhot vol. XV: 150). He presents it as a matter of dispute with Levush (OH 468:1) and others, being of the opinion that it *does* atone. Others, however, such as the Tifferet Yisrael (Yakhin to Pesahim 4:5:24) write explicitly that the offering is not for atonement.

Comment: are these things available online to read in english?

Comment: @Michael16 No, they are not.